# Ищу загрузчик фотографии

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Загрузчик должен будет загрузить одну фотографию профиля и, при этом, передать некоторые данные, помимо файла, обработчику.

Желательно на `JQuery`. `SimpleUpload` и `Uploadify` не подходят.

Comment: Если бы вы уточнили, почему два перечисленных вами плагина не подходят, было бы проще сориентироваться. Парачка плагинов на рассмотрение:

 1. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
 2. http://www.phpletter.com/DOWNLOAD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри в сторону *swfupload* Он вполне позволяет передавать дополнительные параметры.
Но для одного файла лично я использую загрузку через Iframe, куда как проще.